# Gmail REST API - how to "Create the email content in some convenient way" in PHP

Tags: php, swiftmailer, gmail-api

The Gmail docs say I need to `create a MIME email messages compliant with RFC 2822`. - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Given I only have a 'to' address, subject and plain-text body - is the simplest way to achieve this using SwiftMailer (or alternative package)?

If so, how do I make sure the output of SwiftMailer will be suitable for Gmail REST API?

I'll use this function to Base64URL encode it:

```
function base64url_encode($data) {
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

SwiftMailer just works:

```
    //create MIME message using SwiftMailer
    $msg = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setTo(array($data['email']))
        ->setSubject($data['subject'])
        ->setBody($data['message']);

    //base64URL encode message
    $msg = base64url_encode($msg);

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessToken($_COOKIE['access_token']);
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $message->setRaw($msg);

    try {
            $message = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message);
            print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
            return $message;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mime = $message->toString();
```

and then

```
$msg = base64url_encode($msg);
```